# How to implement facebook Credits API using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-credits, koala

How can we implement facebook credits API in Rails 3. Is there any gem or helpers for this?
 Using Koala gem for facebook is it posible to implement credits API.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code is included in this answer: [Is there a Facebook Credits Ruby On Rails gem out there yet? Or ruby version of their Facebook Credits sample app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824035/is-there-a-facebook-credits-ruby-on-rails-gem-out-there-yet-or-ruby-version-of-t/5824719#5824719)

I am trying to figure out how to create my first ever gem and gemify this - expect it pushed in the next few weeks.

Comment: You answer was really useful dude. All the best for your first gem :-)

Comment: NP :-)  ...I have found this place so helpful as I try to learn Rails I like the opportunity to give back a bit!